# Как сделать модальное окно выше меню с тегом <nav>?

Tags: ajax, html5

Добрый день, коллеги!

Нужен совет новичку.

Создаю сайт-визитку. Есть меню с тегом `<nav>`, а выше него кнопка **"Запись на прием"**.

При нажатии на кнопку, выскакивает модальное окно, но почему-то всегда за меню.

Я код модального окна выносил даже за пределы `<html>` , все равно меню с тегом `<nav>` выше.

С чем это связано? [image: Картинка]

Comment: проверь z-index у модального и навигации, скорее всего значение у модального ниже, чем у навигации

Answer (score 1):

Вся проблема видимо в [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) в css.

Посмотрите в css стилях на тег nav какой стоит z-index и уменьшите его или дайте css файл посмотрим вместе.

Comment: Точно. Он вложен в <div id="wb_Extension1">

Comment: #wb_Extension1{
  z-index: 9999!important;
}
nav > ul.menu> li > ul.submenu {
  background: #186471;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 180px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
  -ms-transform-origin:0 0;
  transform-origin:0 0;
}

Comment: @AibekSydygaliev вот, надо уменьшать или выносить если есть возможность, потому что он вылазит даже за фон который появляется с модальным окном, а это не очень красиво.

Comment: Сделал #wb_Extension1{
  z-index: 55!important;
}    и  nav > ul.menu> li > ul.submenu {  z-index: 55;}    Помогло! ВСЕМ СПАСИБО!

Comment: Значит ещё где то есть z-index на другом элементе, судя по скрину у вас модалка bootstrap с z-index:1050 если его не изменяли, так что ищите дальше по nav, если сайт доступен из вне поделились бы ссылкой, посмотрел бы или как вариант посмотрите z-index на .modal классе, может там кто то сделал меньше 55

Comment: Очистил куки - помогло! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Такое поведение возникает, если модальный контейнер имеет фиксированную или относительную позицию либо находится внутри элемента с фиксированной или относительной позицией.

Удостоверьтесь, что модальный контейнер и все его родительские элементы расположены корректным образом.

Самый простой способ исправить проблему - переместить div модала так, чтобы он был вне любых элементов, имеющих специальное позиционирование. Например, сразу перед закрывающим тегом .
Либо экспериментируйте со свойством CSS {position:}, пока проблема не исчезнет (при этом внешний вид сайта может измениться, однако). Порой помогает изменение значения z-index. Точнее без вашего кода сложно разобраться. Возможно, просто где-то не закрыт какой-либо тег.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636667/bootstrap-modal-appearing-under-background
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983110/bootstrap-modal-sitting-behind-backdrop